# How to avoid asynchronous processing in angular js

Tags: angularjs, asynchronous

I'm new in angular js . I want to do authentication . I've to direct to some pages only after checking authentication. I've checkLogin function for that. While calling that checkLogin function it take some processing time. If `true` it redirects corresponding page. If `false` it remains the same page. But while calling the checkLogin function the same time it process the `app.config` function concurrently. I need to to block it. I've to process that only after `chcklogin`.

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute', 'ngResource','ngCsv', 'ui', 'ngSanitize', 'ngQuickDate', 'ui.tree', 'blueimp.fileupload','mentio']);
app.config(function($routeProvider) {
$routeProvider
    .when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'app/views/login.html',
        controller: 'LoginController',
        title: 'Login'
    }).when('/signup', {
        templateUrl: 'app/views/signup.html',
        controller: 'SignUpController',
        title: 'Sign Up'
    }).when('/dashboard', {
        templateUrl: 'app/views/dashboard.html',
        controller: 'DashboardController',
        title: 'Dashboard'});});

app.run(function($rootScope, $location, DataService) {
var unAuthenticatedPages = ["/", "/signup"];
var checkLogin = function() {
    if (!$rootScope.isLoggedIn && unAuthenticatedPages.indexOf($location.path()) === -1) {
        $location.path('/');
    }
}; 
$rootScope.isLoggedIn = true;
   DataService.getUserListById(1, function(user) {
       $rootScope.user = user;
});
$rootScope.$on('$locationChangeStart', checkLogin);});
```

Comment: Please consider typo before posting a question.

Answer (score 0):

angularjs comes with a built in promise library $q which can be injected and used something like this:

```
var doSomething = function() {
  var deferred = $q.defer();

  //do someething here, when you're ready resolve the deferred object
  deferred.resolve();

  //this won't execute until deferred is resolved or rejected
  return deferred.promise;
};
```

You can also return variables with your promise if required. You can then

```
doSomething().then(function() {
  //this executes if the promise is resolved
}, function() {
  //this executes if the promise is rejected
});
```